# Get current user with Spring @SubscribeMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

I use @SubscribeMapping in a Spring Boot application which heavily relies on WebSockets for data exchange. The application is secured with Spring Security.

Client-side I use Stomp over WebSocket:

```
this.socket = new WebSocket(this.socketUrl);
this.stompClient = Stomp.over(this.socket);
this.stompClient.debug = null;
this.stompClient.connect({},
    function(frame) {
        this.$.chartLoader.generateRequest();
    }.bind(this),
    function(e) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            this.connectWs();
        }.bind(this), 2500);
    }.bind(this)
);

this.stompClient.subscribe('/topic/chart/' + chart.id,
    function(message, headers) {
        this.setChartData(chart, JSON.parse(message.body));
    }.bind(this), {
        "id" : "" + chart.id
    }
);
```

Server-side, how can I get the currently logged user in the annotated methods ?

```
@SubscribeMapping("/chart/{id}")
public void subscribeMapping(@DestinationVariable("id") final short id) {
    // Here I would need the current user...
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/chart/" + id, chartService.getChartData(account, sensor, new Date(), new Date()));
}
```

I have tried `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`, but it returns `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to add a [`Principal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html?is-external=true) object as a method parameter. This interface is extended by [`Authentication`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) which has several implementations available (Spring will inject the good one according to your configuration).

```
public void subscribeMapping(@DestinationVariable("id") final short id, Principal principal) {
   principal.getName();    
}
```

[This article](http://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security) may also help you.